# Why Python is not better in multiprocessing or multithreading applications than Java?

Tags: java, python, multithreading, multiprocessing, gil

Since Python has some issues with GIL, Java is better for developing multiprocessing applications. Could you please justify the exact reasoning of java's effective processing than python in your way?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301481/python-java-c-and-parallel-algorithms/6434954#6434954

Comment: Do you know what GIL is?

Comment: This question is wrong. In **multiprocessing** application, the GIL does not become a problem as multiprocessing Python application will happily run concurrently in multiple cores. Java is not better doing multiprocessing than python. multithreading, on the other hand...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The biggest problem in multithreading in CPython is the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (note that other Python implementations **don't** necessarily share this problem!)

The GIL is an implementation detail that effectively prevents *parallel* (simultaneous) execution of separate threads in Python. The problem is that whenever Python byte code is to be executed, then the current thread **must** have acquired the GIL and only a single thread can have the GIL at any given moment.

So if 5 threads are trying to execute some Python byte code, then they will effectively run interleaved, because each one will have to wait for the GIL to become available. This is not usually a problem with single-core computers, as the physical constraints have the same effect: only a single thread can run at a time.

In multi-core/SMP computers, however this becomes a bottleneck. These days almost everthing is running on multiple cores, including effectively all smartphones and even many embedded systems.

Java has no such restrictions, so multiple threads can execute at the exact same time.

Comment: Implementations of Python without a lock will need different memory handling behaviour (GC instead of reference-counting giving rise to indeterminate clean-up). Reference counting in a multi-threaded environment is a bit tricky to do efficiently.

Comment: It appears that Jython does not have the GIL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120354/does-jython-have-the-gil

Answer (score 4):

I would disagree that Python is not better than Java for Multi-Processing application.

First, I am assuming that the OP is using 'better' to mean 'faster code execution' as far as I can tell.

I suffer from 'speed-freak' syndrome, probably from having come from a C/ASM background, so I have spent considerable time getting to the bottom of the "is Python slow?" issue.

The simple answer to that? "It can be." Here's some important points:

1) With a multi-threadded application, Python is going to have a disadvantage to any language that doesn't have something similar to the GIL. The GIL is an artifact of the Python VM in CPython, not the Python language itself.  Some Python VM's like Jython, IronPython, etc do not have a GIL.

2) In a Multi-Process application, the GIL doesn't really apply, and thus you can now start to harness faster execution of your Python code unmolested for the most part by the GIL. I strongly suggest if you want to write large Python code that needs both speed and concurrency, that you learn about Multi-Processing, and possibly ZMQ/0MQ for message passing.

3) Regardless of the GIL, Java displays faster code execution than Python in many areas. This is due to native differences in how Python handles objects in memory:

- A number of Python functions create copies of objects in memory rather than modifying them ( see http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/ for examples)
- Python uses Dict to store attributes for objects, etc. I don't want to distract and delve into these areas, but I can generally say that some of the 'neat' things that Python can do come at a speed cost. It's also important to know that there are ways around the default behaviour if that is causing too high of a speed penalty for you.

4) Some of Java's speed advantage is due to more optimization in the Java VM over Python as far as I can tell. Once you eliminate the differences in how much behind-the-scenes memory/object work is done, Java can often still beat Python. Is it because Java has had more attention than Python? I'm not sure, with enough funding I feel that CPython could be faster.

- Check http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PythonProblems for more discussion on some of these issues.

I will say that I have decided to embrace Python nearly 100% going forward with new code.

Don't fall into the premature optimization trap, and remember you can always call C code in a pinch. Make your code work well, make it maintainable, then start to optimize once the speed of the application isn't fast enough for your needs.

Interesting Benchmarks:

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64/python.php

Further information about Python speed issues can be found here:

http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/van-rossum-python-not-too-slow-188715