# Multi-Threading PHP vs Multi-Threading Python

Tags: php, python, multithreading, pthreads

I know that PHP supports now [Threads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) and i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439061/why-python-is-not-better-in-multiprocessing-or-multithreading-applications-than) Python multi-threading is not better than muli-threading in java since Python has some issues with GIL.

So i sepposed that Python multi-threading will also not be better than muli-threading in php. As PHP use the same style like in java to create threads, in addition php uses pthread to implements threads, which is wide popular library.

What do you suggest ?

Comment: Are you asking for a language recommendation? As always, the answer is, "use whatever is most appropriate for your project". If you have to have threads not constrained by the GIL, then don't use Python.

Comment: How's Java related to this question?

Comment: if python threading not better than java, so i assumed that python threading is also not better than php.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: No idea what the question is ... but there is no GIL in PHP ...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Python does indeed have a Global Interpreter Lock. This means you can't use threads to spread one program over multiple cores on the same machine. But running the same program on multiple cores is not what threads was designed for anyway, and doing so is not easy. However, you can use the `multiprocessing` module to spread a program over multiple cores, so this is no big deal.

I don't know if PHP has a GIL or not, but as you see above it's really not important.

Even if PHP's threading was slightly better than Pythons, that's a bad reason to choose PHP. In fact pretty much any reason except "I don't have a choice" is a bad reason. [Ref1](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) [Ref2](https://wiki.theory.org/YourLanguageSucks#PHP_sucks_because%3a)

Comment: It's not strictly true that "you can't use threads" to utilize multiple cores.  The GIL means that no two cores can be executing in the main CPython's interpreter code concurrently.  However, you'll still see some benefits for some workloads even with the GIL with threading.  However, as you say, the multiprocessing module (in the standard libraries since 2.6) is the better way to go.  Note that some C/binary extensions to CPython (such as Numpy) are written to release the GIL and have their own multi-threading support.  So some computational workloads can benefit from multiple cores as well.