# time.sleep that allows parent application to still evaluate?

Tags: python, maya

I've run into situations as of late when writing scripts for both Maya and Houdini where I need to wait for aspects of the GUI to update before I can call the rest of my Python code. I was thinking calling time.sleep in both situations would have fixed my problem, but it seems that time.sleep just holds up the parent application as well. This means my script evaluates the exact same regardless of whether or not the sleep is in there, it just pauses part way through.

I have a thought to run my script in a separate thread in Python to see if that will free up the application to still run during the sleep, but I haven't had time to test this yet.

Thought I would ask in the meantime if anybody knows of some other solution to this scenario.

Comment: `I have a thought to run my script in a separate thread in Python to see if that will free up the application to still run during the sleep, but I haven't had time to test this yet.` Yes, that is how you do concurrency.

Comment: Threading is good.  Multiprocessing is too.

Comment: What I am unsure of with this is whether it will still allow the parent application to continue processing. This would be a new thread created within the Python script, so I am guessing this would still tie up Maya/Houdini the same as before but allow more than one stream of Python code to process. I will test this soon.

Comment: Initial tests look good in Maya. I think this works. Cool! Thanks guys.

Comment: Well, it did solve the problem at hand. However, running a previously working script inside a thread now gives me a number of errors for "# TypeError: Flag 'force' must be passed a boolean argument" Found this thread on CGTalk relating to the issue.. http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php/t-973723.html

Comment: FWIW if you use multiprocessing instead of threading, it will spawn a new Maya instead of running in a separate thread. Which stinks, since multiprocessing is a more powerful toolkit :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maya - or more precisely Maya Python - is not really multithreaded (Python itself has a dodgy kind of multithreading because all threads fight for the dread [global interpreter lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265687/why-the-global-interpreter-lock), but that's not your problem here).  You can run threaded code just fine in Maya using the threading module; try:

```
import time
import threading
def test():
   for n in range (0, 10):
       print "hello"
       time.sleep(1)
 t = threading.Thread(target = test)
 t.start()
```

That will print 'hello' to your listener 10 times at one second intervals without shutting down interactivity.

Unfortunately, many parts of maya - including most notably ALL user created UI and most kinds of scene manipulation - can only be run from the "main" thread - the one that owns the maya UI. So, you could not do a script to change the contents of a text box in a window using the technique above (to make it worse, you'll get misleading error messages - code that works when you run it from the listener but errors when you call it from the thread and politely returns completely wrong error codes).  You can do things like network communication, writing to a file, or long calculations in a separate thread no problem - but UI work and many common scene tasks will fail if you try to do them from a thread.

Maya has a partial workaround for this in the [maya.utils](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/files/Python_Python_and_threading.htm) module. You can use the functions executeDeferred and executeInMainThreadWithResult.  These will wait for an idle time to run (which means, for example, that they won't run if you're playing back an animation) and then fire as if you'd done them in the main thread. The example from the maya docs give the idea:

```
import maya.utils import maya.cmds
def doSphere( radius ):
    maya.cmds.sphere( radius=radius )
maya.utils.executeInMainThreadWithResult( doSphere, 5.0 )
```

This gets you most of what you want but you need to think carefully about how to break up your task into threading-friendly chunks. And, of course, running threaded programs is always harder than the single-threaded alternative, you need to design the code so that things wont break if another thread messes with a variable while you're working. Good parallel programming is a whole big kettle of fish, although boils down to a couple of basic ideas:

1) establish exclusive control over objects (for short operations) using [RLocks](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#rlock-objects) when needed
2) put shared data into safe containers, like Queue in @dylan's example
3) be really clear about what objects are shareable (they should be few!) and which aren't

Here's  [decent (long) overview.](http://kurt.seifried.org/2010/05/31/python-performance-part-1/)

As for Houdini, i don't know for sure but [this article](http://nccastaff.bournemouth.ac.uk/jmacey/Python/HoudiniExample/tools_10threading.html) makes it sound like similar issues arise there.

Comment: Thanks! Great detailed response. This is exactly the hurdle I was starting to run into yesterday when going down the threading module route. Getting lots of error messages about boolean values not working. Haven't figured out a solution to it yet, but I will be exploring the maya.utils example you gave at a later time. I've worked around it for now and will be returning to this as I see it as being a very good general knowledge things for the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Just wanted to add, works great in Houdini with just the threading module. Maya is the only one being cranky with threading.

Comment: Latest link to maya.utils for Maya 2022: https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-9B5AECBB-B212-4C92-959A-22599760E91A

Answer (score 0):

A better solution, rather than sleep, is a while loop. Set up a while loop to check a shared value (or even a  thread-safe structure like a Queue). The parent processes that your waiting on can do their work (or children, it's not important who spawns what) and when they finish their work, they send a true/false/0/1/whatever to the Queue/variable letting the other processes know that they may continue.