# Python function call not runing correcly from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, port, maya

I'm having some trouble getting this to work, i'm trying to append GUI texts to a window that allready exists, i'm using the python interpreter for autodesk maya, i attach here part of the host script where i check for multiple connections and try to add the text for each connection.

**The problem** comes when calling the *interpHostData()* function from inside the while loop inside the thread, it dosnt add anything to the window;

But whenever i call the function by itself outside of a thread it works correctly.

If anyone has a clue on how can i fix this i would apreciate it, thanks in advance.

```
def hostUpdate():
    global socketHost
    global clientL
    clientL=[]
    cmds.text('mt1',e=1,l='Update Process Started...')
    while 1:
        connectionMain,addressMain=socketHost.accept()
        cmds.text('mt1',e=1,l='Connected with: %s'%str(addressMain))
        #----------Different Thread for each connection
        tid=thr.start_new_thread(hostRecieve,(connectionMain,addressMain))
        clientL.append([connectionMain,addressMain,tid])
        cmds.text('mt1',e=1,l='Thread started with: %s'%str(addressMain))

def hostRecieve(connI,addrI):
    global clientL
    cmds.text('mt1',e=1,l='Recieve Process Started...')
    while 1: #------------------------------------Loop to keep listening for connections
        try:
            cmData=connI.recv(4096)
            interpHostData(cmData) #--------------IF I CALL FROM HERE DOSN'T WORK
        except:
            for cl in clientL:
                if connI==cl[0]:
                    clientL.remove(cl)
            cmds.text('mt1',e=1,l='Disconnected from %s'%str(addrI))
            break

def interpHostData(cmDataC):
    global cliLayout
    tplD=cmDataC.split(',')
    if tplD[0]=='0':
        cID=tplD[2]
        cmds.setParent(cliLayout)
        cmds.text(cID+'_1',l=tplD[1])
        cmds.text(cID+'_2',l=tplD[3])
        cmds.text(cID+'_3',l=tplD[4])
        cmds.text(cID+'_4',l='_')
        cmds.text(cID+'_5',l='_')
        cmds.text(cID+'_6',l='_')
        cmds.text(cID+'_7',l='_')
        cmds.text(cID+'_8',l='_')
        cmds.columnLayout(cID+'_9')
        cmds.progressBar(cID+'_10',h=10)
        cmds.progressBar(cID+'_11',h=10)
        cmds.setParent(cliLayout)
        cmds.text(cID+'_12',l='_')
        cmds.text(cID+'_13',l='Online')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only run Maya ui commands from the main thread. You can use [`maya.util.ExcecuteDeferred()`](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/Python-Python-and-threading-htm.html) to get around this to some degree but it takes extra work and won't be as responsive as a true multi-threaded app.  Longer explanation [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106877/time-sleep-that-allows-parent-application-to-still-evaluate)

Comment: Thanks a lot @theodox