# Multithreading in Python scripting

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am working on encoding a video. For that I need a thread that will encode the video while it is played and will exit when the video stops.
How do I make this happen?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Note that because of the [GIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265687/why-the-global-interpreter-lock), you're probably going to want to use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should put encoding in main process and put playing in a thread. Here is example, you have to fulfill it with your own code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from threading import Thread

def encode_video():

    t = Thread(target=start_play, args=[])
    t.start()
    t.join()
    # here is code for encoding
    pass

def start_play():
    # here is code for starting
    pass


if __name__ =='__main__':

    encode_video()
```

Hope it helps.