# Can I separate Python set update into several threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, multiprocessing

I'm doing some brute-force computing and putting the results into a set `all_data`. Computing chunks of data gives a list of numbers `new_data`, which I want to add to the big set: `all_data.update(new_data)`. Now while the computational part is easily made parallel by means of `multiprocessing.Pool.map`, the update part is slow.

Obviously, there is a problem if one has two identical elements in `new_data`, that are absent in `all_data`, and trying to add them at the same moment. But if we assume `new_data` to be a set as well, is there still a problem? The only problem I can see is the way sets are organized in memory, so the question is:

> Is there a way to organize a set structure that allows simultaneous addition of elements? If yes, is it realized in Python?

Comment: `multiprocessing` provides primitives for sharing data and synchronization. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393879/4371276)

Answer (score 1):

- In pure Python, no. Due to the GIL, all *Python* code (including manipulations with built-in structures) is single-threaded. The very existence of GIL is [justified by eliminating the need to lock access to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265687/why-the-global-interpreter-lock).

  - Even the result fetching in `multiprocessing.Pool.map` is already sequential.
- [ParallelProgramming article in SciPy wiki](http://wiki.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming) outlines related options on parallel *code* but I didn't find anything directly regarding off-the-shelf *concurrent data structures*.

  - It does, however, mention a few C extensions under "Sophisticated parallelization" which do support parallel I/O.
- Note that a `set` is actually a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) which by its very nature cannot be updated in parallel (even with fine-grained locking, sub-operations of each type (look-up, insertion incl. collision resolution) have to be sequenced). So you need to either

  - replace it with some other data organization that can be parallelized better, and/or
  - speed up the update operations, e.g. by using [shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721915/shared-memory-objects-in-python-multiprocessing)