# Threading in Python using multiple cores

Tags: python, python-2.7, pthreads, gil

As far as I know, Python's threading library uses POSIX threads for threading and it does not run on multiple cores. So is it possible that we implement a multicore threading system for Python threads using Open MP?

Comment: I think the `GIL` is the issue : https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: See the wiki on [parallel processing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) for ways to do it.

Comment: @Rayu please consider to mark an answer as accepted and upvote  answers that helped you

Answer (score 6):

CPython ("default" Python implementation) is not utilizing multiple cores because of [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). So every Python statement has to hold that lock.

But modules that are written in C may release interpreter lock before time-consuming operation. I.e. **numpy** does that: http://wiki.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming

They have handy example for that:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def f(x):
    print x
    # This statements hold GIL and cannot be run
    # in two parallel threads 
    y = [1]*10000000
    [math.exp(i) for i in y]

def g(x):
    print x
    # This statements fall to NumPy C code
    # than release GIL and can be multithreaded
    y = np.ones(10000000)
    np.exp(y)
```

Since OpenMP is also a tool for C, I think that is what you seek for.

Answer (score 3):

[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

> The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency,
>   effectively side-stepping the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) by using
>   subprocesses instead of threads. Due to this, the multiprocessing
>   module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on
>   a given machine. It runs on both Unix and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

CPython has a Global Interpreter Lock a.k.a `GIL`. The GIL ensures that only one thread runs in the interpreter at once. Can your multicore threading system beat the GIL?

More about GIL:

- [Understanding the Python GIL](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf)
- [Why the Global Interpreter Lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265687/why-the-global-interpreter-lock)