# Data structure for UDP Server parsing JSON objects in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, udp, server

I have a UDP server listening to incoming traffic in a thread. The messages come from an external device in JSON format, for example, {"_id": "0x00", "status": "on"}. This information needs to be parsed by ther UDP handler and stored in a dict of objects (or update if the _id exists) At the moment I can receive and parse JSON, but not entierly sure how to store this data or handle it correctly. I would like to use a Queue in the UDP Handler and a separate Msg Handler that processes the queue but not sure if it's the right way of doing it.

Please note: I have re-written the code omitting some syntax etc.

```
# I create a node server thread in the main of my program with IP/PORT

class NodeServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__():
        self.server = UDPServer((address, port), UDPHandler)

    def run():
        self.server.serve_forever()

class UDPServer(socketserver.ThreadingUDPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class UDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    data_q = queue.Queue()

    handler = NodeHandler(data_q)
    handler.start()

    def handle():
        try:
            # receive the message from client
            data = self.request[0].decode("UTF-8")

            # check if it's in json format

            # HANDLE THE MESSAGE
            self.data_q.put(data)

            # stop the thread
            self.handler.join()
            # send an "ACK" msg back to the client
      except: Exception as e:
            #handle

class NodeHandler(threading.Thread):
    table = NodeTable()

    def __init(data_q):
        self.data_q = data_q

    def handle():
      # get the string message from the queue (filled by the UDPHandler)
      msg = self.data_q.get()

      # check if the "_id" field exists in the current node table

      # if it exists in the table, find it, update the fields from json

      # otherwise, if it's a new "_id": create a new node
      json_msg = json.parse(msg)
      node = Node(json_msg["_id"])
      # set other node parameters from the json object, status etc

      # update the node table with the new information from the message
      table.put(nd)
      #
    def join():
        # join thread

class NodeTable():
  # the table is a dictionary with ID and a Node object, ie {0x01: Node}
  table = {}
  def put(_id, node):
      self.table[_id] = node

  def get(_id):
      return self.table[_id]

class Node():
    id = 0
    def __init__(id):
        self.id = id
        # new node
    # other node functions
```

- Should the NodeHandler be created in the UDP Handler as a separate thread or just an handler object?
- Does the Node Table need to be global, if not, how to access it outside of the server? Perhaps just passing it as an object.
- Is NodeTable a good data structure for holding unique node objects, or there is a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can implement a UDP server which processes incoming messages in
an infinite loop much more simply with these lines of code:

```
 import socket

 def udp_server(udp_ip, udp_port, ...):
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
   sock.bind((upd_ip, upd_port))
   while True:
     data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
     ...process data...
```

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication for more details
and discussion.

The arguments to `udp_server` are the udp IP and port, and whatever
other data structures the server needs to interact with.

And kicking this off into its own thread is very easily acccomplished
with:

```
 import threading

 t = threading.Thread(target = udp_server, args = (...))
 t.start()
```

2) The NodeTable class is just a wrapper around a python dictionary,
but it seems that you want to have multiple threads access it at the
same time. In that case you should read this SO answer:
[(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1312389/866915).

Depending on what other threads besides the server thread can do to
the node dictionary you may or may not need a lock.

To summarize, where is how I would write the code:

```
 def main():
   nodes = {}     # use a simple dict for storing the nodes
   lock = RLock() # if you need this
   # pass nodes and lock to server thread and start it
   t = threading.Thread(target = udp_server, args = (udp_ip, udp_port, nodes, lock))
   t.start() 
   ...
```

At this point the udp server is running and the main thread can access the node
table via the variable `nodes`.

Does the main thread need to be informed when new nodes have been added to
the node table? Then perhaps a Queue is what you want. You would 1) create it
in `main()` and 2) pass it to `udp_server`:

```
 def main()
   nodes = {}     # use a simple dict for storing the nodes
   lock = RLock() # if you need this
   q = Queue()    # create a Queue and pass it to the udp server
   # pass nodes and lock to server thread and start it
   t = threading.Thread(target = udp_server, args = (udp_ip, udp_port, nodes, lock, q))
   t.start() 
   # process entries from the Queue
   while True:
     item = q.get()
     ... process item...
```

and in the udp server function `...process data...` will put something onto the queue:

```
   while True:
     data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
     ...json decode, etc. ...
     q.put(...)
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I have a server thread which runs the udp_server like you suggested and puts the items back in the queue which I can access from the serer thread. I haven't used mutex locks in python before, but should have no trouble following your example!