# How to parallelize task in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing, ping, flask-restful

I'm sending a XHR request to my Flask server in order to do several pings on a network

### Resource

```
def get(self, site_id):
    …
    for printer in printers:
        hostname = printer['hostname']
        response[site_id][hostname] = network_utils.ping(hostname)

    return response
```

#### Ping

Below `shell.execute` I'm using [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to run a native `ping`:

```
def ping(hostname):
    command = ['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', '-q', hostname]

    response = shell.execute(command)
    return output_parser.ping(response['results'])
```

#### Output

```
{
    "test-site": {
        "avg": 0.093, "max": 0.093, "mdev": 0.0, "min": 0.093,
        "1.1.1.1": { "avg": null, "max": null, "mdev": null, "min": null},
        "1.2.3.4": { "avg": null, "max": null, "mdev": null, "min": null},
        "127.0.0.1": { "avg": 0.061, "max": 0.061, "mdev": 0.0, "min": 0.061}
    }
}
```

#### Questions

The pings are run sequentially making the request super slow (tens seconds, how can I speed up thing?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the best choice is threading because your issue is **I/O bound**. I'm using [Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) to limit to 5  threads.

I'm sending the response dict to the ping dict are thread safe, but you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312331/using-a-global-dictionary-with-threads-in-python) if you think about something more complicated.

```
def get(self, site_id):
    …
    semaphore = threading.Semaphore(5)
    threads = []

    for printer in printers:
        hostname = printer['hostname']
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=network_utils.ping,
                          args=(semaphore, response, site_id, hostname)))

    # Start and wait to all threads to finish
    map(lambda t: t.start(), threads)
    map(lambda t: t.join(), threads)

    return response

def ping(semaphore, response, site_id, hostname):
    semaphore.acquire()

    command = ['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', '-q', hostname]
    response = shell.execute(command)
    ping_data = output_parser.ping(response['results'])

    response[site_id][hostname] = ping_data

    semaphore.release()
```

Comment: Do I need to `acquire()`/`release()` inside of the `ping()` function or can I do it around the `thread.append()`?

Comment: You must do it inside, when appending to `threads` I'm just adding a thread object to a lilst, just when calling `t.start()` the actual thread is starting

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez  BTW, I don't know the length of `printers` but If it small list, you can remove the semaphore. But if it is too big - you don't want to open 5K threads at the same time.

Comment: printers list should stay below 200 items

Comment: my code is not runing the target: https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/c3f43a3b895c17b0be801706be7a3c2a

Comment: I had to tweak it, I will post my solution

Answer (score 2):

Make the subprocess asynchronous via [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), for example.

```
from gevent import subprocess
import gevent

def ping(hostname):
    command = ['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', '-q', hostname]
    return subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

def get(self, site_id):
    …
    # Start all the pings in parallel, asynchronously
    # Use dict to reference host: ping subprocess
    # as results will come in at different times
    pings = {printer['hostname']: ping(printer['hostname']) 
             for printer in printers}
    # Wait for all of them to complete
    gevent.wait(pings.values())
    for hostname in pings:
        response[site_id][hostname] = output_parser.ping(pings[hostname].stdout.read())
    return response
```

Comment: why did you modify the `ping()` function?

Comment: check_output is a blocking function and will always turn the subprocess calls sequential. With gevent making them asynchronous, need to first start all the subprocesses in parallel and check output once they all complete.

Comment: Note that asynchronous means without threads. Gevent can easily handle hundreds/thousands of parallel subprocesses, especially since yours are I/O bound. With threading, performance suffers once number of threads exceeds number of physical cores available.

Answer (score 1):

Upvote [Or Duan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39037929/802365) as mine is based on his answer:

#### Resource

```
class Ping(Resource):
    def get(self, site_id):
        site_hostname = mast_utils.list_sites(site_id)['results'][0]['hostname']
        printers = mast_utils.list_printers(site_id)['results']['channels']

        response = network_utils.parellelize(network_utils.ping, site_hostname, printers)
        return response

api.add_resource(Ping, '/ping/<string:site_id>/')
```

#### *network_utils.py*

```
def ping(hostname):
    command = ['ping', '-q', hostname,
               '-w', '1',
               '-W', '1',
               '-i', '0.2'
               ]

    response = shell.execute(command)

    return output_parser.ping(response['results'])


def collect(task, response, **kwargs):
    hostname = kwargs['hostname']

    response[hostname] = task(**kwargs)


def parellelize(task, site_id, printers, **kwargs):
    response = {}
    kw = kwargs.copy()
    kw.update({'hostname': site_id})
    collect(task, response, **kw)

    printers_response = {}
    threads = []
    for printer in printers:
        hostname = printer['hostname']
        kw = kwargs.copy()
        kw.update({'hostname': hostname})

        threads.append(
            threading.Thread(
                target=collect,
                args=(task, printers_response),
                kwargs=kw
            )
        )

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
        thread.join()

    response[site_id].update(printers_response)

    return response
```

#### *test_network_utils.py*

```
class NetwrokUtilsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_ping_is_null_when_host_unreachable(self):
        hostname = 'unreachable'

        response = network_utils.ping(hostname)

        self.assertDictEqual(response, {
            'avg': None,
            'max': None,
            'mdev': None,
            'min': None
        })

    def test_ping_reply_time_when_reachable(self):
        hostname = '127.0.0.1'

        response = network_utils.ping(hostname)

        self.assertGreater(response['avg'], 0)

    def test_ping_with_only_a_site(self):
        site_hostname = 'localhost'
        printers = []
        response = {}

        response = network_utils.parellelize(network_utils.ping, site_hostname, printers)

        self.assertGreater(response[site_hostname]['avg'], 0)

    def test_ping_with_printers(self):
        site_hostname = 'localhost'
        printers = [
            {'hostname': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 22},
            {'hostname': '0.0.0.0', 'port': 22},
        ]

        response = network_utils.parellelize(network_utils.ping, site_hostname, printers)

        self.assertGreater(response[site_hostname]['avg'], 0)
        self.assertGreater(response[site_hostname]['127.0.0.1']['avg'], 0)
```